# Why is the list of all sites in the Stack Exchange dropdown not sorted?

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-exchange-button, stack-exchange

I am not sure it's the right place to post this as it's common to all Stack Overflow sites.
I suggest sorting sites by user reputation and then alphabetically in the all-sites list of the Stack Overflow button.

Comment: Meta Stack Overflow is the hub for all of the sites in the network - for questions about the engine and network itself - you're fine here. (:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This list is now sorted by reputation first, and then alphabetically to make it easier to find the site you are looking for.

Answer (score 12):

The list is sorted, it just hasn't kicked in for you yet based on your reputation.

Sites where you have > 200 reputation will be sorted by reputation, highest reputation accounts at the top.

Sites where you have < 200 reputation will then be listed in random order.
e at the top.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. In my opinion it will be more friendly to sort according to reputation to bring more accessed on the top as it is now and sort the remaining alphabetically. The two lists may be then separated by a horizontal line separator.

Comment: Now I have 209 rep in Programmers and it's still not on the top !!

Comment: @M.Sameer: The list checks your reputation only once a day, at 0:00 UTC.

Comment: random sorting order is the worst way to go, takes me an average of 5 secs to find the site I want to see - honestly why not use good old alphabet?

Comment: @Rebecca Can you explain what you mean by the last line: "e at the top". Is it a typo? or do you mean that it is sorted alphabetically beginning with the letter 'e'?

Comment: Why is there a minimum of 200 rep to be sorted? Why can it not be sorted based on the actual rep? Also it can also be sorted by last accessed right?