# Did Stack Exchange change the algorithm that determines how sites are listed in the "All-Sites" menu?

Tags: support, bug, stack-exchange-button, stack-exchange

According to [Order of all sites in StackExchange menu](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92397/order-of-all-sites-in-stackexchange-menu), the ordering if the sites in the Stack Exchange "All Sites" menu is set so that all sites where one has 200+ reputation will appear at the top of the list. The remaining sites will all appear in a random order, listed after the sites where the user has 200+ rep.

This means that I should see the following sites at the top:

- Stack Overflow
- Programmers SE
- Project Management SE
- Meta Stack Overflow
- Mechanics SE
- Fitness and Nutrition SE
- OnStartups
- Workplace SE

Before today, I was seeing this list at the top, consistently. However, as of today, the sites where I have 200+ reputation no longer appear at the top. Instead, the *entire* list appears to be randomized, as per the screenshot below:

[image: All Sites Menu]

I am logged in, and I've seen the same behavior now on several SE sites where I have an account. The list of sites is random, and in this example, the top 2 sites are those for which I'm not even a member.

Is this a bug? Is this a change in the policy of how these sites are ordered? If it's not a bug, what is the thought process behind such a change?

Comment: I'm speculating that it had something to do with the API outage (seem [you aren't the only one](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4987651#4987651)) and now possibly caching, but I can't say for certain. My list is correctly ordered at the moment.

Comment: lol beat me to it. I was just going to edit my tags ;)

Comment: What browser? I am not experiencing this problem either, but at least one other user experiencing this problem is using Firefox. And the symptom is similar to other reasons I recently stopped using Firefox. :-)

Comment: I am the other person that Aaron is refering to. The only thing from my side that may have caused this is a recent (just today) Firefox update. So, this may be causing it. I'll try again tomorrow with cache emptying perhaps to see if there is any change.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - I'm using Chrome, but I can replicate the problem in Firefox as well.