# Change Stack Exchange Account from top navigation

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, user-accounts

I think it would be very good idea to add `Account` section to Stack Exchange drop-down. The `Account` section would show details as follows (similar to `Account` section in My Account page):

- Number of all accounts
- Account name (which is a link to a account)
- Account reputation and account badges

Example design:

[image]

I believe lots of users have many Stack Exchange accounts and that would give them very easy way to switch between them.

Comment: Interesting idea, but I will note that this partially already exists: right now the "all sites" view is sorted by reputation (for sites where you have over 200 points), so your top sites appear there already. Sites where you have less than 200 rep are [sorted randomly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/84512/155160).

Comment: @Anna Thank you for clarifying that. I was not aware of that threshold and sorting strategy. Now I think my proposed feature is rather duplicate of existing feature.

Comment: I'm gonna call it "by design" for the moment, then. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite this is [secretly incorporated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160416/change-stack-exchange-account-from-top-navigation#comment465002_160416) through the *all sites* tab, I really like the rep/badge display, it could be nice to add these into the *all sites* tab:

[image]

<sub>(I do have rep/badges in Mathematics and IT Security, but for simplicity of creating an example of #1 below, I omitted these)</sub>

This way:

1. It is <del>easier</del> easy to see in what sites have registered.
2. You can quickly check your rep/badges from other sites.