# Add sites I'm registered on to the main StackExchange menu

Tags: feature-request

It'd be great to have a list of the stackexchange sites I'm registered on in the StackExchange menu for quick navigation.

[image: Here]

Answer (score 6):

The "All sites" list [is sorted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/84512/155160) by reputation when you're signed in. It starts with the sites you have the most reputation on and goes backwards for all sites where you have over 200 reputation. The sorting is random for sites where you're below 200 rep.

Comment: Aha! I see. Perhaps the registered sites can be somehow highlighted?

Comment: @Sorantis why highlight them? Shouldn't you already know if you're registered with them or not?

Comment: What are the odds of the random sorting exactly equaling descending order? I see the sites listed in descending order the same as [SE.com](http://stackexchange.com/users/7745/michael-myers?tab=accounts) except that two 103-rep accounts are swapped.

Comment: Is this still accurate? I noticed today the order is completely random every time I check

Comment: @DHall You only have two sites with over 200 rep, so those two should always be at the top, but everything else will look random. Are you seeing something different?

Comment: @AnnaLear Yes - normally I see SO/Photo at the top, followed by the other sites I'm registered on, but today they're all completely random. I've asked a friend and on chat here, and it seems like it's just me having the issue.