# Ordering of "My Communities" in the Stack Exchange drop-down menu appears to be broken

Tags: feature-request, bug, top-bar, sorting, communities-list

I would have thought that someone must have asked this already but [apparently not](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=ordering%20of%20the%20stack%20exchange%20drop%20down%20menu).

The ordering of the Stack Exchange drop-down menu is at times [in parts] logical, and then there are random positionings. Take a look at this:

> [image: Stack Exchange site drop down menu]

[This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84511/why-is-the-list-of-all-sites-in-the-stack-exchange-dropdown-not-sorted#answer-84512) to the question [Why is the list of all sites in the Stack Exchange dropdown not sorted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84511/why-is-the-list-of-all-sites-in-the-stack-exchange-dropdown-not-sorted), does not explain the ordering that I see:

> Sites where you have > 200 reputation will be sorted by reputation,
>   highest reputation accounts at the top.
>
> Sites where you have < 200 reputation will then be listed in random
>   order. e at the top.

It is not because I need to wait 24 hours either, as it has been like this for nearly a week. In fact, it has always been badly ordered - only now am I analysing the order, or trying to.

3D Printing messes up the ordering at the top of the list - is this because I have always been on that site, in the past few weeks, and so it has been positioned as a favourite?

Surely Ask Ubuntu should be just below Stack Overflow, and Arqade at the bottom?

If I scroll *down* that menu, it gets even more random, and not all of them are < 200, so the explanation in the answer above, doesn't appear to apply:

> [image: StackExchange site drop down menu - scrolled down]

Comment: Are you sure you did not edit the order? Just to be sure, click the "edit" link then "reset to default list" and see if this "fix" your problem.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - I don't think I can see a "reset to default list", do you mean the "edited" link, or the "edit" link? Regardless, I can't see it in either.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmQ3f.png then in the bottom of the list: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTtVu.png

Comment: @ShadowWizard - ah, sorry, I thought you were referring to the weird order due to the editing of the question clash (by Ale and myself). Now I see that you are referring to the drop down menu. Apologies.

Comment: You do know that you can sort these however you like, right? Or am I missing something? At the very top of the list, there is an "edit" button... If you've **ever** changed the order, I don't think it will override what you chose any more. You have to update it manually. Have you tried clicking "reset to default list"?

Comment: @Catija - As I commented on Shadow Wizard's answer, which has now been deleted, I hadn't noticed the edit link before today, so no, I haven't changed it. In fact the list order has been changing at the top in the past week/month as my rep on Super User and Meta has changed

Comment: I can't very well see content that has been deleted :D I'm currently about 160 rep shy of that.

Comment: @Catija - Sorry... I am not sure why ShadowWizard deleted their answer, it was quite informative

Comment: It was wrong answer, since you did not edit the list and it's not ordered in the order you joined sites. /cc @Catija