# How can I sort "Your Communities" by reputation?

Tags: feature-request, support, user-interface, sorting, communities-list

I would like the option to organize sites in "Your Communities" by reputation.

As users like myself become active on different sites, changes in reputation can lead to the list displaying in a [seemingly random order](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/297094/351462).

[image: Unsorted community list]
<sub>List of 9 favorite communities (unsorted)</sub>

Currently, I'm only able to sort the community list by reputation either by manually rearranging sites or resetting back to the default list of 5 communities.

[image: Default community list - 5 sites]
<sub>Default list of top 5 communities (sorted by reputation)</sub>

**Is it possible to display more than the top 5 communities in order of reputation?**

Comment: It *should* be sorted by reputation afaik, so something might be broken.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297094/ordering-of-my-communities-in-the-stack-exchange-drop-down-menu-appears-to-be