# Defining Stack Exchange menu listed communities

Tags: support, communities-list

Complementing [How can I sort "Your Communities" by reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298330/712835):

I would like to choose my main Stack Exchange communities, I mean the ones are listed in *Your communities* session at *communities menu*.

**Is it possible?**

[image: Communities menu]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an "edit" button that appears on the right side of the list on the same row as "Your Communities". It appears the user style/script you're using to make a dark theme is hiding that link.

Either disable that style/script, or see if you can find that "edit" link by moving your mouse where it should be.

Comment: Looks like the screenshot was taken from the topbar on stackexchange.com itself and we might not be allowing edits there (I can't check at the moment). Opening the same drop-down here on MSE should turn up the edit link.

Comment: Perfect, I could find it and edit my communities list as desired! Thanks